# How to import a local stored xml file in Vue and edit it?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, xmlhttprequest, vuejs2, vue-resource

I am new to VueJS and want to re-write part of my plain Javascript SPA with Vue JS now (just for training and learning). **I created my project with Vue-CLI**. And here is a part of my file structure now:

```
---src
   |---assets
       |---logo.png
   |---components
       |---loadXML.vue
       |---table01.vue
       |---table02.vue
   |---static
       |---ABC.xml
   |---app.vue
```

I recently struggling with this problem:

I want to **load and read a *local stored xml-file* (in static folder) into Vue instance and later parse through it and do some edit on it**.

In my plain Javascript, it is very simple to do this by using:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var xmlDoc = this.responseXML;
    }
}
xhttp.open('GET', 'ABC.xml', true);
```

And I can do every thing I need to the `xmlDoc`

But in Vue JS, I find it is very hard to load and read (parse) a xml file, even I searched a lot, I can't find a proper way to do it clean. I have already tried the following ways:

**(1) By using the import to directly import the local xml file into Vue:**

```
import xmlFile from '../static/ABC.xml'
```

Because **I can directly import local json file** by using:

```
import jsonFile from '../static/XYZ.json'
```

But **it won't work for xml file**, I got this:

```
Module parse failed. You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type
```

**(2) With help of vue-resouce:**

```
this.$http.get('../static/ABC.xml').then(function(data)) {
     var xmlDoc = data;
}
```

But then I got this:

```
http://localhost:8080/static/ABC.xml 404 (Not Found)
```

It seems like **the relative path will not work within the http request**.

**(3) By using the old code in VueJS:**

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var xmlDoc = this.responseXML;
    }
}
xhttp.open('GET', '../static/ABC.xml', true);
```

But I got the same problem in (2). So I think the relative path is just not right for a http request because the files need to be complied and re-organized somehow.

I know it's kind of rare to load and read even edit a xml file with Vue JS but I would appreciate it if someone has done it before and point out what I should do at this stage.

Answer (score 3):

I use Axios:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8080/file.xml')
                .then(response => {
                    var xmlText = response.data;
});
```

So you put the xml file in the static folder, but that one is considered as the root folder.